# LEFT JOIN SUBQUERY

Tags: sql

Olá, estou com uma pequena dúvida sobre SQL já que não entendo nada sobre isso.Tenho uma tabela onde estou fazendo um select para ver as atualizações com uma subquery e faço um LEFT JOIN qui está o código:

```
SELECT a.id, a.nome,
(SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM postagens as c WHERE c.data_cadastro > 
b.data_acesso AND c.id_categoria = a.id AND deletado = 0) as atualizacoes
FROM postagens_categorias as a
LEFT JOIN postagens_categorias_view as b ON a.id = b.id_categoria
WHERE a.deletado =0 AND a.id != 3 ORDER BY a.nome DESC
```

E dá este resultado aqui:

[image: SQL SELECT]

Os dados que eu gostaria seria:

```
Projetos   25
Estágios   24
Divulgação 21
```

Acredito que deveria usar um GROUP BY em algum lugar, se eu usar o DISTINCT no começo ele continua duplicando os valores só que no lugar de NULL, 0.

Aqui está a tabela de postagens_categorias:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Postagens_categorias_view:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Postagens:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço essa parte?

Comment: já tentou com distinct e group by na coluna atualizacoes?

Comment: Acredito que tens que fazer com o INNER JOIN.

Comment: Detalhe suas tabelas na pergunta, facilitará o nosso entendimento do problema para dar uma possível resposta. Com o código que você colocou, suponho que seja mais interessante você tirar o subselect e fazer um group by.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que eu entendi do seu problema, a solução é a seguinte:

```
SELECT a.id, a.nome, count(d.id_categoria) as atualizacoes
FROM postagens_categorias as a
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_categoria from postagens_categorias_view b 
                INNER JOIN postagens c 
                    ON c.id_categoria = b.id_categoria 
                WHERE c.deletado = 0 AND 
                    c.data_cadastro > b.data_acesso
              ) d
        ON a.id = d.id_categoria
WHERE a.deletado = 0 AND
    a.id != 3
GROUP BY a.id, a.nome
ORDER BY a.nome DESC
```

Comment: Ficou bem perto do que eu queria, o único problema é que esse não retorna nada quando não tem nenhuma atualização, no caso eu preciso que retorne 0, exemplo : Projetos 0, Estágios 24 e Divulgação 0

Comment: Essa informação de atualização fica em `postagens_categorias_view` ou em `postagens`? Na tabela que essa informação estiver, você usará o `left join`. Por isso é interessante você colocar na sua pergunta a definição das tabelas, facilita o entendimento.

Comment: Blz, melhorei ali para o entendimento colocando as outras tabelas faltantes. A ideia é quando tiver postagem nova ela "categoriza" em qual das áreas e separa cada categoria com as suas atualizações.

Comment: Alterei a resposta. Como pode haver `postagens_categorias` sem registro em `postagens_categorias_view`, nem em `postagens` é necessário que seja left join em ambas as junções para que os registros em `postagens_categorias` apareçam. Alterei o `count(*)`, por `count(c.*)`, estou na dúvida se funcionará, por favor faça o teste. Espero que funcione.

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou, deu essa mensagem:
 
#1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a '*) as atualizacoes 
FROM postagens_categorias as a
    LEFT JOIN postagens_cat' na linha 1

Comment: Você usando left Join e o count(*) dá certo? Aparece a resposta que deseja?

Comment: Aparece mais ou menos a resposta, pois mostra somente as categorias com atualizações e as sem atualizações não aparece.

Comment: Então, @MarcosSchneider conservei com um amigo e ele propôs essa consulta que coloquei na resposta, por favor teste aí.

Comment: A explicação para a outra solução não funcionar está aqui https://stackoverflow.com/a/10949318/9916784 , como eu tinha colocado na cláusula `where` campos que faziam parte da tabela que foi juntada com `left join`, quando vinha `NULL` ele excluía a linha para realizar o count, por isso não aparecia.

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar Isnull (quando for null substitui zero) se não der certo, coloca CASE

```
SELECT a.id, a.nome, isnull(count(*),0) atualizacoes
FROM postagens_categorias as a
    LEFT JOIN postagens_categorias_view as b ON a.id = b.id_categoria
    LEFT JOIN postagens as c on c.id_categoria = a.id
WHERE a.deletado = 0 AND
    c.deletado = 0 AND
    a.id != 3 AND 
    c.data_cadastro > b.data_acesso
GROUP BY a.id, a.nome
ORDER BY a.nome DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Se o filtro do seu select estiver certo, o código pode ser esse aqui:

```
SELECT T.ID,
       T.NOME,
       T.ATUALIZACOES
FROM (
SELECT A.ID,
       A.NOME,
       (SELECT COUNT(C.ID)
        FROM   POSTAGENS AS C
        WHERE  C.DATA_CADASTRO > B.DATA_ACESSO
        AND    C.ID_CATEGORIA = A.ID
        AND    DELETADO = 0) AS ATUALIZACOES
FROM   POSTAGENS_CATEGORIAS AS A
LEFT   JOIN POSTAGENS_CATEGORIAS_VIEW AS B
ON     A.ID = B.ID_CATEGORIA
WHERE  A.DELETADO = 0
AND    A.ID != 3
GROUP BY A.ID,
         A.NOME) T
ORDER BY T.NOME DESC
```